# Angularjs app affects jQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have portal what is partially based on jQuery. 
I rewrite one component to Angular, injected it with

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController"></div>
```

And sidebar what is used on whole project stop working on page where angular app is present.

Tried to change script ordering, but it don't help. 
If remove angular.js  tag from html navigation working ok.

Comment: Add a fiddle/plunkr that reproduces this issue.

Comment: tried do it on plunker and it works. Maybe someone could advice about direction what can affect jQuery https://plnkr.co/edit/ebcNGIYHlyeRpuoOfjwY?p=preview

Comment: solved! It was inner issue related to some code inside project.